# Turn functions to class methods in python

Tags: python-3.x, function, methods, subclass

To better structure the code I wanna create this subclass of string:
class StringQuotes(str):
pass:

And put these functions and variables in there:

```
SINGLE_QUOTE = "'"

    
def StringMask_QuoteSingle(s: str ) -> str:
    return s.replace(SINGLE_QUOTE , SINGLE_QUOTE *2)
 

def StringSingleQuote(s, quoteChar = SINGLE_QUOTE ):
    s = StringMask_QuoteSingle(s)
    return StringQuote( s, quoteChar)

def StringQuote(s, quoteChar ):
    return quoteChar + s + quoteChar
```

`SingleQuote` should be static constants. (For sake of simplicity it'll be also okay if it is not really readonly)

When doing so (-> see answer to my question) I encountered some problems / questions I thought it might be good to share that question here.
I'll nice to have a review and to see ya ideas improvements.

---

Well that's what I come up with:

```
class StringQuotes(str):
        
    SingleQuote = "'"
    
        
    def Mask_QuoteSingle( _ : str ) -> str:
        return str.replace( _, "'" , "'" *2 )
                  
    
    def SingleQuote( _ , quoteChar = SingleQuote ):
        _  = _.Mask_QuoteSingle( )
        return StringQuotes.Quote( _ , quoteChar)
    
    def Quote( _ , quoteChar ):
        return quoteChar + _  + quoteChar
```

Instead of `self` I choose `_` since it looks nicer.
However compared to a function all the need for this `self.` still clutters up view.

Questions:

1. Why can't I do `_.replace(...)` ? Why it has to be

   str.replace( _, ... )? Are there other ways?
2. ... and about `str.replace( _, "'")` how can I make it to use `SingleQuote`?

   - just `replace( SingleQuote,` =>complains it doesn't find
     SingleQuote

   > =>NameError: name 'DoubleQuote' is not defined

   - `replace( _.SingleQuote,` or `replace( StringQuotes.SingleQuote,`

   > =>TypeError: must be str, not method
   > What? Why SingleQuote is a method/function? I don't get it.
   > It's a str or variable - but not function!  Is Python turning class variables into a 'property get()' (<- I seen stuff like this in Visual Basic)
3. Why the use of `SingleQuote`  works in here:

   def SingleQuote( _ , quoteChar = SingleQuote ):
4. About `return StringQuotes.Quote(`
   Can I avoid duplication of `StringQuotes` and write something like `me.Quote(`

Answer (score -1):

Here is the answer to 'my' question:

```
class StringQuotes(str):
        
    SingleQuote = "'"
    
        
    def Mask_QuoteSingle( _ : str ) -> str:
        return str.replace( _, "'" , "'" *2 )
                  
    
    def SingleQuote( _ , quoteChar = SingleQuote ):
        _  = _.Mask_QuoteSingle( )
        return StringQuotes.Quote( _ , quoteChar)
    
    def Quote( _ , quoteChar ):
        return quoteChar + _  + quoteChar
```

Instead of `self` I choose `_` since it looks nicer.
However compared to a function all the need for this `self.` still clutters up view.